# How to read Android App Shortcuts?

Tags: android, metadata, android-support-library

If I wanted to create my custom launcher with new [App Shortcuts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html) 
how could I do?

I'll explain, the reference report this:

> If your app targets Android 7.1 (API level 25) or higher, you can define shortcuts to specific actions in your app. **These shortcuts can be displayed in a supported launcher**. Shortcuts let your users quickly start common or recommended tasks within your app.

These shortcuts can be displayed in a supported launcher...but few lines later:

> **Note:** Although other apps can't access the metadata within your shortcuts, the launcher itself can access this data. Therefore, these metadata should conceal sensitive user information.

So..how do I read the shortcuts of apps that implement them if you can not read the `metadata`? And how does Nova Launcher do??

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/LauncherApps.html for shortcut-related methods.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare it helped!!